# Awaiting termination of multiple ExecutorServices for a fixed time period

Tags: java, multithreading, time, executorservice

I have the following wrapper that exposes the `awaitTermination` method of an `ExecutorService`

```
public class AwaitableTermination {
    protected final ExecutorService executorService;

    public AwaitableTermination(ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
        return executorService.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Typical inputs are 500 milliseconds.  The user understands that these times are approximate.

I have a new requirement for a `CompositeAwaitableTermination` class that extends `AwaitableTermination`, that contains a list of `ExecutorService` objects.  `awaitTermination` should return `true` if all `ExecutorService` objects are terminated within the input time span, else `false`.

I could `awaitTermination` of each `ExecutorService` in its own thread, but this seems extremely wasteful not to mention imprecise (there's no guarantee that all of the threads will execute in a timely manner).

A possible single-threaded approach is to iterate through the `ExecutorServices` and reduce the timeout as appropriate for each object

```
private final List<ExecutorService> services;

public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
    Queue<ExecutorService> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(services);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean result = true;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    while(result && (service = queue.poll()) != null) {
        long currentTimeout = timeout - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        if(currentTimeout > 0) {
            result = service.awaitTermination(currentTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this approach strikes me as being very error-prone for larger collections of `ExecutorServices` (at present I'm expecting no more than 4 objects in the `services` collection, but I don't want to have to rely on that assumption).  Is there a more precise / elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with this code.

If you have *large collections* (say 100k+) of `ExecutorService`, you should be more concerned about the actual number of threads!

`awaitTermination` takes no time at all if the service is already shutdown or if no task are pending and it is most likely the case if you have a lot of ExecutorService running otherwise your system should already be suffering. So even for *large collections*, this code should not have any issue.

Comment: I'm concerned that I'm going to get false negatives due to loop overhead.  Let's say that a loop iteration takes a minimum of 1ms (for a terminated `ExecutorService`); given a timeout of 500ms, a collection of more than 50 `ExecutorServices`, and an initial `ExecutorService` that returns `true` after 450ms, the method will return `false` even if all of the `ExecutorServices` have terminated because the timeout (reduced to 50ms after the first iteration) will decrement by 1ms on each iteration and will expire before the final iteration.  But I'm probably overestimating the loop overhead.